# MarginLeft not working in IE/Firefox within function (but works from console)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I have a JQuery function which distributes DIVs evenly depending on the browser size.

- This is likely a coding issue.  People are saying it works in Chrome and Opera but not other browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/wMpBS/1/

It's a lengthy function, but basically I've traced the code and it seems as though it is properly calling something like

```
 $("#div123").css("marginLeft", "15px");
```

And in IE the margins go back to 0 when calling the function.  But when I type the above line into the console it works.

Comment: try to put css position:absolute and run..

Comment: That doesn't really fix it.

Comment: $("#div123").css("margin-left", "15px"); try this

Comment: @Dave Have you set the doctype of the page?

Comment: Not that I know of.  I don't know much about what DOCTYPE does.

Comment: For what it's worth, your fiddle doesn't work in Firefox either.

Comment: The doctype may be a red-herring: it's important to have a valid doctype (otherwise IE will render your page in Quirks Mode), but jsFiddle has a doctype by default, so if the jsFiddle example demonstrates the problem, then it isn't a doctype issue.

Comment: Update: your test works in Chrome and Opera, but fails in all the other browsers I've tested it with (Safari, Firefox, IE9, IE10). Clearly this is NOT an IE-specific issue.

Comment: Thanks for the testing info.  It helps narrow it down.

Comment: playing with the fiddle in IE10 and boxArray doesn't seem to be defined - I start there

Answer (score 0):

It was a coding mistake I made.  The function is so convoluted I barely understand it, but it was setting the margins unnecessarily twice.

I remed out this line

```
//for (i = 0; i < boxArray.length; i++) $(boxArray[i]).css("margin", $(boxArray[i]).css("margin"));
```

This is the fixed version:

http://jsfiddle.net/wMpBS/8/